# Contact page is not loading

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I have uploaded all the files using filezilla but the contact page is not displaying. It works fine in local server. I Can't figure out what's the problem.

Please check the site here: [**infinityadv.com.np**](http://infinityadv.com.np/)

***Edit:***

```
<div id="menubar1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="wh"><a href="#">Who we are</a> 
        </li>
        <li class="wh"><a href="#">What we do</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I first click at the link it opens but from second time it won't work.

```
ul {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:160px;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    ;
}
li {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:30px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width:120px;
    height:36px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
ul li a:link {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
ul li a:visited {
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

---

```
ul li a:active {
    margin-top:-44px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:35px;
    width:120px;
    height:60px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(0, 153, 255);
    background-image:url(../image/hoverbutton.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
ul li a:hover {
    margin-top:-44px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:35px;
    width:120px;
    height:60px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(0, 153, 255);
    background-image:url(../image/hoverbutton.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

---

```
.wh :hover {
    margin:-43px 0 0 -19px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:35px;
    width:160px;
    height:60px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:rgb(0, 153, 255);
    background-image:url(../image/hoverbutton1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Check the file. Seems like an HTML error to me. Also, put some code in your question.

Comment: Do u mean this [site](http://infinityadv.com/).. In this Page the Contact is showing correctly

Comment: @coolprarun I highly doubt that.

Comment: Its infinityadv.com.np @coolprarun

Comment: it works fine when i open it in my local drive. but not open when uploaded to server. im using filezilla for this uplaoding.

Comment: Nope the Website is broken.. "could not find infinityadv.com.np" @user2698742

Comment: Are you sure about the site name? "infinityadv.com.np" .com is first domain name so there can't be something on right side of it.. Or you want to tell me that you have a domain com.np?

Comment: working fine here.. http://infinityadv.com.np/ _Windows 8_ and *Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95 m*

Comment: Welcome to SO. As far as I know such questions are not tolerated here. Just giving an url and asking what is not ok is not the best thing that you can do. However your contact page ends up with an open body tag. So, I'll suggest to check your php script (or whatever you use for the back-end) and investigate what may cause this.

Comment: <div id="menubar1"> 
<ul>

<li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="wh"><a href="#">Who we are</a> </li>
<li class="wh"><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>


</ul>

</div>

Comment: my domain is .com.np here another error too. when i first click at the link it opens and second third time it wont work

Comment: ul {margin: 0 auto 0 auto; list-style-type:none; margin-left:160px; padding:0; text-decoration:none; ; }

li {color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; padding-top:30px;   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width:120px; height:36px;  float:left; display:block; text-align:center; }



ul li a:link {color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; display:block;}
ul li a:visited{color:rgb(255,255,255);}

Comment: To me, the contact page is opening blank with some background image.

Comment: ul li a:active {margin-top:-44px; font-weight:bold;  padding-top:35px; width:120px; height:60px; text-decoration:none; color:rgb(0,153,255); background-image:url(../image/hoverbutton.png);  background-repeat:no-repeat; } 

ul li a:hover {margin-top:-44px; font-weight:bold;  padding-top:35px; width:120px; height:60px; text-decoration:none; color:rgb(0,153,255); background-image:url(../image/hoverbutton.png);  background-repeat:no-repeat; }

Comment: .wh :hover  {margin:-43px 0 0 -19px; font-weight:bold;  padding-top:35px; width:160px; height:60px; text-decoration:none; color:rgb(0,153,255); background-image:url(../image/hoverbutton1.png);  background-repeat:no-repeat; }

Comment: That's the excat problem it open in my local drive. @Mr_Green

Comment: seems to be a problem with url paths. I think you are giving some paths as absolute. The server would have taken care automatically if the paths were relative.

Comment: Thanks @mr_green it was just a silly mistake ive done. Thanks again for helping. but the contact page problem stil remains

Comment: cant solve the problem even after deleting and uploading it many times . Do the PHP inserted in this page make any difference?

Comment: let me insert the PHP included here.

Comment: <div id="contactus">
   
  <form name="htmlform" method="post" action="html_form_send.php">
<table width="330px">
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
 
<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email *</label>
 </td>

Comment: <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone </label></td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="22" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

Comment: here's the php file
 $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
     
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

Comment: $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

Comment: $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
     
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

Comment: // create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
 
<!-- place your own success html below -->
 
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
 
<?php
}
die();
?>

Comment: @user2698742 Please edit that in to your question. The comments make it nearly impossbile to follow the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be that you have not given correct links in all pages menue divs thats why on clicking **what we do**  link converted to yourpastlink# and then you never go to other links.

Contactus.html page is not uploaded correctly.
open directly **http://infinityadv.com.np/contactus.html**

Comment: my second problem is solved but still can't get the contact page let me delete all files and check it again .

Comment: i got it that the php error, i've included in my page i delete the php file and now its working but how could i use the contact us form without php. any thought about this. @mr_green